# Ansible - when condition not working as expected

Tags: ansible

I stopped splunk on target server and I want Ansible to start it if it is not running based on the output of the first command. I got the status of splunk from the target server with the following command:

```
service splunk status | grep -i running | grep -v grep
# output:
splunkd is not running.
```

Snippet of the playbook:

```
- shell: service splunk status | grep -i running
  register: SERV

# - debug: var=SERV.stdout

- shell: echo OK
  register: ECHO

- debug: var=ECHO.stdout

# - debug: msg="SPLUNK is NOT Running and will be Started"

- service: name=splunk state=started
  when: SERV.stdout == "splunkd is not running."
```

The "when" condition does not work as expected. If Splunk is not running, the "when" condition works. But if splunk is running, Ansible still starts splunk.

Q: How can I configure the "when" condition so it will start splunk if 'Spunkd is not running.' is in the output of the first command?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try Ansible Service module, reference [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_module.html)

something like this should work, not sure if you are looking for something else.

```
- name: Start service splunk, if not started
  service:
    name: splunk
    state: started
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: it is not the issue I have that service command and it works when slunk is not running, but it should not be executed when splunk  is running

Comment: Exactly, whether the service should be started or not should be based on the output of a previous command.

Comment: @KevinC Ok but `started/stopped` are idempotent actions that will not run commands unless necessary. So they don't run unless and until the state is different. If it is already started that task will be skipped.

Comment: Sure, I agree in that sense, the task shouldn't be skipped by design, because that's how Ansible works. But OP wants to start the service based on a certain when condition.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
- service: 
    name: splunk 
    state: started
  when: "'splunkd is not running' in SERV.stdout"
```